# Trying to use type library but I get a File Not Found error

Tags: c++, vba, visual-c++, dll

I have a type library that was created in Visual C++, and I'm trying to call its functions in VBA.  I have two files: `utility.dll` and `utility.tlb`.  I included a reference to the library in my VBA project by going to References, and browsing to `utility.tlb`.  But when I compile the project, I get an error message:

```
File not found: utility.dll
```

I have placed both library files in the same directory as the .xlsm file that has the VBA project.  I thought maybe it was a DLL registration issue, so I tried running `regsvr32` on `utility.dll` and got the following error message:

```
The module "utility.dll" may not compatible with the version of Windows 
that you're running.  Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) 
or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe.
```

I have access to the source code, .sln files, etc. for the C++ project that created the library files.

What should I do next to make my VBA project able to use this type library?

Comment: Use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, that gave me the same response about `may not compatible` [sic].

Comment: In Visual Studio go to solution properties and on the Build tab select your platform - if it's a 64bit class library intended for 64bit office then select `x64` for platform target instead of any CPU

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the type library had the DLL search path hardcoded to a folder that only existed on the development machine.  Changing this eliminated the error.